# OCaml: dune missing library, opam says its there

Tags: ocaml, opam

I have a dependency called 'sets', which has been build in a local directory 'dep/sets'.

`opam list` gives the following:

`sets  1.0.0  pinned to version 1.0.0 at file:///...`

`opam pin` gives:

`sets.1.0.0  rsync  file:///...`

But `dune utop` gives

`Error: Library "sets" not found.`

I've seen https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/272 but that's pretty old and uses jbuild, which is now deprecated.

*Some Version Info:*
OCaml 4.07.0
Opam 2.0.3

Comment: The linked issue hints at the fact that dune can only include dependencies that are findlib libraries. Do you see this `sets` listed in `ocamlfind list`? Your question led me to find https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/connection-between-libraries-in-opam-dune-and-findlib/2536/7 which is an interesting discussion about the relation between opam packages and findlib libraries re: dune.

Comment: Yeah, `ocamlfind list` gives `sets  (version: n/a)`.  I'll check out that thread though, thanks